# how to push rebased branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I have a feature branch `branch-foo`. It was branched off from `master` branch, which is our stable/production branch.

I have the following work process:

1. I pushed `branch-foo` to remote repo & created a pull request for team to review.
2. Then, on my local branch `branch-foo`, I did code updates based on pull request review comments. But I don't yet push it.
3. At this point, I noticed the there are new merge to `master`, so I fetched the latest master branch & did a rebase. That's rebase my `branch-foo` to the head of latest `master`.
4. Now I try to push `branch-foo` with my code updates. And get rejected git error:

```
 ! [rejected]    branch-foo -> branch-foo (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'bitbucket.org:myorg/my-project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

5. I see above error suggests me to pull, so I then tried `git pull origin branch-foo`, but get another error:

```
From bitbucket.org:myorg/my-app
 * branch            branch-foo -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

So, I get stuck that I am not able to push my changes, neither can I pull the remote. Our team enforces to only allow fast-forward, no direct merge allowed.

How can I properly solve this problem so that I can push my rebased branch to my pull request branch now?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have rebased `branch-foo` after you pushed it. Instead, you should have merged `master` *into* `branch-foo`.

Answer (score 2):

you start with

```
                 A---B---C foo
                /
           D---E master
```

you push, and master was updated:

```
                 A---B---C foo and origin/foo
                /
           D---E---F---G origin/master
```

you did some modification,
you fetch  rebase on master:

```
                 A---B---C origin/foo
                /
           D---E---F---G origin/master
                        \
                          A'---B'---C'  foo
```

foo is not a fast-forward of origin/foo, but it is a fast forward of master.
You need to push with force as you are not doing fast forward on foo:

To avoid bad surprise avoid

```
git push --force
```

just use:

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

you will have

```
           D---E---F---G origin/master
                        \
                          A'---B'---C'  foo and origin/foo
```

Comment: Why ? The rebase (on master) has been done, just the push should be done now.

Comment: I solved it by deleting the remote branch and push. It is safer for me. But I am not sure what is the best way to both not violating fast forward convention and push the changes.

Comment: I agree with @Ôrel. If the OP is the only author working in foo and pushing that work to the remote, I don't see any reason against force-pushing rebased changes. Furthermore, `--force-with-lease` was designed specifically for OP's scenario.

Comment: Thanks all. I tried `git push --force` and `git push --force-with-lease`, both yields the error:```fatal: The current branch branch-foo has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin branch-foo```

Comment: As you have deleted the branch you need to recreate it, doing the command `git push --set-upstream origin branch-foo`